# algorithm complexity: Strassen's algorithm is polynomially faster than n-cubed regular matrix multiplication. What does "polynomially faster" mean?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, multiplication

Strassen's algorithm is polynomially faster than n-cubed regular matrix multiplication. What does "polynomially faster" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question has to do with the theoretical concept of "complexity".
As an example, the regular matrix multiplication is said to have the complexity of O(n^3). This means that as the dimension "n" grows, the time it takes to run the algorithm, T(n) is guaranteed to not exceed the function "n^3" (the cubic function) with respect to a positive constant.
Formally, this means:

There exists a positive treshold n_t such that for every n >= n_t, T(n) <= c * n^3, where c > 0 is some constant.

In your case, the Strassen algorithm has been demonstrated to have the complexity O(n^ log7). Since log7 = 2.8 < 3, it follows that the Strassen algorithm is guaranteed to run faster than the classical multiplication algorithm as n grows.

As a side-note, keep in mind that for very small values of n (i.e. when n < n_t above) this statement might not hold.

Answer (score 2):

Algorithms with complexity `O(n^3)` and `O(n^2)` both are polynomial. But the second is **polynomially faster**.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I assume it means that both algoritms have a ploynomial run time, but the Strassen algorithm is faster.

That's only because the standard (even for a cube) is polynomial.

Anyway, I don't think the term "polynomially faster" is a standard term.